# Vscode extension track changes of html in previewHtml

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm displaying a `TextDocumentContentProvider` using `previewHtml`. Is it possible to track the addition of text into the textbox that i'm displaying in this previewHtml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't do this automatically but your extension can certainly use the previous html preview contents to track changes or generate a diff